# Extraer una cadena en base al identificador 15 y colocar al final el pedazo extraído y invertirlo al revés

Tags: java

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente código con mi cadena en la parte de abajo, y el resultado que me debe mostrar debe ser de la siguiente manera:
“mar_en_java_y_basededatos. progra_gusta_Me”

Pero actualmente me muestra el resultado así, pero así no lo quiero, debe salir como hago mención arriba:
“mar_en_java_y_basededatos. argorp_atsug_eM”

Me piden hacerlo con los arreglos a cómo está en el código, solo es la ultima cadena que no me sale como quiero.

```
String cadena =“Me_gusta_programar_en_java_y_basededatos.";
char[] cadenaInicio = new char[cadena.length() - 15];
char[] cadenaFin = new char[15];
for (int i = 15; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
    cadenaInicio[i - 15] = cadena.charAt(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    cadenaFin[14 - i] = cadena.charAt(i);
}
String nuevaCadena = new String(cadenaInicio) + " " + new String(cadenaFin);
System.out.println(nuevaCadena);
```

Comment: El identificador 15... ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: @Lozano, en mi código pongo una cadena,  debo cortar todo el pedazo de cadena hasta llegar al carácter 15 contando de izquierda a derecha, luego ese pedazo que corte debo recorrerlo al final del otro pedazo restante, de la cadena, el pedazo restante se recorrería al principio y una vez que puse el pedazo cortado al final de la cadena ahora invertir ese pedazo al revés, si quieres ejecuta el código que tengo, ya hace todo a cómo lo quiero, pero hay un detalle, el pedazo que recorro al final de la cadena no me lo pone como yo quiero, solo es esa parte que aún me falta.